# Is this sentence a cleft sentence or not?

Tags: meaning, grammar, clefts

> People can agonize over the purchase of greeting cards. They will spend an enormous amount of time searching for just the right words to convey their thoughts. "It is usually an embellishment to the emotional statement that is being made with a gift." Together the two are intended to convey silent passions or feelings to the recipient.

1) "It is usually an embellishment to the emotional statement that is being made with a gift."
Is this sentence a cleft sentence or a sentence containing a postmodifying relative clause?

2) If this is a cleft sentence, how can "usually" be included? Is it possible? I think "Usually" doesn't belong to not only "It is ~ that" construction but also "an embellishment to the emotional statement is being made with a gift"

3) If this is a sentence containing a postmodifying relative clause, what does "It(the subject of the sentence)" indicate in the paragraph?

4) In the sentence, does "with" mean "using"? that is, as in "make of"
or what?

Comment: Have you tried converting the sentence into a non-cleft sentence?

Comment: @CJDennis Yes, as seen in my question 2), I know that "An embellishment to the emotional statement is being made with a gift." works. But I think that doesn't necessarily exclude the possibility of a sentence containing a postmodifying relative clause. So I want to be convinced by others with a good reason.